# Android: how to update our API/Library code, that other developers use in their applications, separate from their updates?

Tags: android, android-service, android-library

I've done a bunch of searching, both here and elsewhere, and just not zeroing in to what looks like the appropriate answer (maybe I'm not using the correct terminology?).

Here's the scenario:

Imagine writing an API to evaluate and manipulate photos. You'd like to deliver (deploy?) your library/service as a package so that other developers can make use of it.

Other developers will write apps that would benefit by using your API. These multiple apps may end up on the same users' device. Naturally, each company will have its own development/deployment/update schedule that may not dovetail with updates to your API library/service.

Later, you come up with more efficient ways to implement some of the features and would like to deploy those improvements on your own schedule without requiring the developers using your API to update *their* apps.

So, the questions are:

1. How do I write my API/Library so that other developers can use it in their apps, and still maintain control over when/how updates to my API/Library are deployed?
2. If Developer-A makes their app available for download, how will they declare a dependency for my API/Library to ensure it's also installed?
3. If Developer-B also has their app installed, and then Developer-A's app gets uninstalled, will my API/Library also be uninstalled?
4. When it's time to update the API/Library, can I mark it for update on the Play Store and expect it to be updated on users devices *even if the apps that depend on it are not?*

I understand a number of Android features that allow implementation sharing between apps. What I'm missing is how to deploy my "bundle of features" so that an end user doesn't have to install two apps (mine and Developer-A's) in order for Developers-A's app to function, **and** be able to separately manage updates.

Thanks in advance for any/all insights you might have.

Comment: You either have a library app like [OpenCV Manager](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/platforms/android/service/doc/index.html) or each app has to bundle the version of the library its integrated against. You might want to link to the sources that makes you believe your scenario is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the link @MorrisonChang. But, as far as "...this scenario is possible." - it's why I posted the question, <i>I don't know whether is is possible</i>. If it isn't, well then, I'm out of luck.